# Две cms на одном домене

Tags: .htaccess, cms

есть site.ru на WP с с кучей страниц(овер 5000), нужно поставить новый сайт на джумле так, что бы не терлись старые страницы, т.е. что бы работали два движка..придя по старой ссылке попадал на старый сайт..по новым ссылкам и главная на новый...(переносить старые страницы тот ещё гемор)
думаю поставить джумлу в папку 1, в htaccess назначить главную site.ru/1/index.php...а вот как быть со старыми адресами?
если в htaccess прописать
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/archives/.* #это название во всех старых ссылках
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/ [L]
прокатит???
и как будут обрабатываться ссылки?
сильно не пинайте..я новичок))

З.Ы. Все таки я лошара))) все оказалось гораздо проще чем думал..надо было просто поменять главную в htaccess...старые ссылки заходят..главная новая..новые ссылки тоже работают..

Comment: На IIS я делала просто через прокси (URL Rewrite), т.к. разные части сайта обрабатываются тремя разными движками. Наверно в htaccess тоже можно такое настроить. Папки разных частей сайта не перемешивались и лежат в разных местах.

Comment: ясно..а кто нибудь может сказать синтаксис правильный??

Comment: По htaccess я не подскажу, был бы IIS. Думаю кто-нибудь ответит еще...

Comment: спасибо и на этом)..буду по старинной русской традиции..методом тыка))